# css grid: children items do not extend to full height

Tags: flexbox, css-grid

I have a grid container div (`display: grid`) which is inside a full height (flex) parent:

`.scss file`

```
  .parent { /* this layout is full height */
    display: flex:
    flex-direction: column;

    .layout-grid {
       flex: 1;  /* this makes my grid to take all available height of parent */
       display: grid; 
       grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
       grid-template-rows: 1fr;
       grid-template-areas:
         "left main"
         "left main";
    }
    .left { /* this child is not full height*/
       grid-area: left;
    }
    .main { /* this child is not full height */
       grid-area: main;
    }
  }
```

`.tsx file`

```
<div className='parent'>
   <div className='layout-grid'>
      <div className='left'> Left </div>
      <div className='main'> Main </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The outer blue border is `.layout-grid` (`display: grid`) which is properly full height.

But I can't get the children of my grid to extend full height even if the grid is properly full height. I have tried `justify-items: stretch` with no success.

But if I give the `.layout-grid` a specific, defined height, not `flex:1` nor `height: 100%` but a specific value (e.g `height: 90vh`), then children content expand to full height.

Is this the way css grid is supposed to work? (in other words: in order for children to take up full height, the grid parent container should have a specific value (not flex:1 or %) )? or there is a mistake somewhere in my style?

Comment: Yes, a parent must have a **calculable** height for any `%`, `flex` or `fr` value to work properly.

Comment: Note however that you have a typo `display: flex:` - you have a colon instead of a semi-colon in `.parent`. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OJVMEyg